# Angular promise callback not firing inside constructor method, but firing in object literal method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constructor, promise, angular-promise

Let's suppose an angular service that encapsulates a pure Javascript model. It has a simple async method that returns the same parameter it receives using a promise resolve (just for demo).

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('MyModel', ['$q', function ($q) {
    function MyModelConstructor() {
      this.test = function(myParam) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (myParam) {
          // Not triggering then callback
          deferred.resolve(myParam);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }

    return MyModelConstructor;
  }]);
```

After calling the test method, the callback is never triggered. However, if I attach the test method as a literal to an object created by the constructor, everything works fine:

```
it('should not fail!!!', function() {
  myModelExample = new MyModel();
  var result;
  expect(result).toBeUndefined();
  myModelExample.test(111).then(function(funresult) {
    result = funesult;
  });
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(result).toBe(111); // But it fails
});

it('should have working promise', function() {
  myModelExample = new MyModel();
  var result;
  expect(result).toBeUndefined();
  myModelExample.test = function(myParam) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
      if (myParam) {
        deferred.resolve(myParam);
      }
      return deferred.promise;
  }
  myModelExample.test(111).then(function(funresult) {
    result = funresult;
  });
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(result).toBe(111); // This way does not fail
});
```

What is the difference in terms of triggering the callback between the constructor created method and the literal one? How can the test method attached in the constructor trigger the callback?

[Here is a Plunker with the example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IabnLh9JzUJehSeHiI83?p=preview)

Comment: How are you invoking the `test` method and with what argument? Is that argument truthy? Is the  `deferred.resolve(myParam);` statement getting executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things wrong: a typo

```
result = funesult;
```

And you haven't defined `myModelExample` inside the test, so

```
myModelExample = new MyModel();
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YdsuoJMkrccPjMb3e2jC?p=preview

Comment: The problem is that I had to create the model for each it testing element. So as soon it's added in the beforeEach block, it works.

Thank you!

Edited my Plunker

Answer (score 1):

You should test inside `.then` has fired. `.then` is fired on `$rootScope.apply()`

```
  it('should not fail but it fails!!!', function() {
    var result;
    myModelExample = new MyModel();
    expect(result).toBeUndefined();

    myModelExample.test(111).then(function(funresult) {
      result = funresult;
      expect(result).toBe(111); // NOPE :(
    });

    $rootScope.$apply();

  });
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UWBvHorznTdPHrsxA2Hb?p=preview

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the problem if you do it in the plunker.  `myModelExample.test()` promise is not returning

Comment: @tyler updated answer. Can test by changing `expect(result).toBe(111);` to `expect(result).toBe(112);` which fails as expected.

Comment: There you go...`expect` should be inside the promise callback and `apply` should be at the end of the `it` block

Comment: Actually that's not necessary, only defining `myModelExample` is necessary (not putting `expect` inside the promise).  See my plnkr for example

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/w3lDprPJVk6HSVSpXI7i?p=preview

1) `MyModel` wasn't being instantiated in the test.
2) `$rootScope.$apply` and `expect` should be inside of the promise callback

Comment: This is also not actually running the test.  Change 111 to 112 in the `expect` and it will still pass

Comment: Once you put the expect inside the then callback, it never executes, so that's why it works. The failing expect is never executed.

Comment: The issue with my response is that the `rootScpope.$apply` is in the callback.  The `expect` should occur in the callback because, in a real life scenario, the promise might not resolve immediately (as it does in the author's code).  If the promise does not resolve immediately, and `expect` is outside of the callback, then `expect` will be called before  `result = funresult` can be set.